# How can I hide the sidebar in MediaWiki?

Tags: templates, hide, mediawiki, sidebar

I would like to be able to hide the whole sidebar (navigation, search, toolbox) and **reclaim the space**. In other words, the page should widen to fill the space used by the sidebar.

I don't want to do this for every page but only for specific pages, so preferably using a template.

I have got a template which hides the sidebar but, crucially, does not reclaim the space:

```
<css>
#column-content {margin: 0 0 .6em 0;}
#content {margin: 2.8em 0 0 0;}
#p-logo, .generated-sidebar,
#p-lang,
#p-tb,
#p-search {display:none;}
#p-cactions {left: .1em;}
#footer {display:none;}
</css>
```

This is using the [PageCSS](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageCSS) extension.

Anyone know I can I modify this to reclaim the space - or have another solution?

**Update:** After help from Adrian Archer (see below) I've discovered that the problem is in my customized skin. Reclaiming the space *does work* with **Monobook**. Anyone know what the particular part of the monobook skin is I need to copy? I've tried several things and I *think* it is in `main.css` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Adrian Archer's help (see his response) + the hard work of a colleague, I have a working example (probably works for all skins). Create a template (e.g. `Template:Hide sidebar`) with these contents:

```
<css>
#column-content {margin: 0 0 .6em 0;}
#content {margin: 2.8em 0 0 0;}
#p-logo, .generated-sidebar, #p-lang, #p-tb, #p-search {
   display:none;
}
#p-cactions { left: .1em; }
#footer { display:none; }
#mw_content { margin-left:0.2em; }
</css>
```

Then just add `{{Hide sidebar}}` to any page you require it. The sidebar area will be reclaimed by the page. This difference with my question is the second to last line: `#mw_content { margin-left:0.2em; }`

Comment: Not mentioned is that you need to have an extension to allow css or any html in templates. Here is the one I assume you're using http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageCSS

Comment: @Frug: good point, I think it was the [CSS extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS). Please let me know if it works and I will update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Frug: actually, I just reread the question, there I was using the [PageCSS extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPageCSS), I think you need that.

Comment: Space is still not being reclaimed with the latest version of MediaWiki

Comment: 1. Add `#column-content ` in front of `#content {margin: 2.8em 0 0 0;}`, that helped me to make it work.
2. I put this CSS in Stylish (Firefox add-on), no need to install an extension, and I can toggle sidebar visibility on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in the Common.css to make sure it is correct.

The only thing I can think could be the problem (and I am not a CSS expert) is that it is being loaded at the wrong time. Try putting it not in a template, does it work then?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrian - I've not been able to try out your suggestion yet - will reply as soon as I can. Note though that the code above does work (hides navigation bar) but I want the page to shift to the left to reclaim that space.

Comment: the FAQ ( http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_hide_the_left_vertical_navigation_toolbar ) seems to indicate that it should reclaim that space. When I put that code at the bottom of my Common.CSS it did work as expected.

Comment: OK, thanks Adrian - I look forward to trying it out. So did that happen *for all* pages - how did you get it only to work for certain pages?

Comment: @Adrian - tried it (the version when F11 is pressed in MediaWiki:Common.js) but the screen area was not reclaimed.

Comment: @Adrian - also with the MediaWiki:Common.css version, it did not reclaim the space. I wonder why it worked for you?

Comment: Did you put it at the bottom of your MediaWiki:Common.css? I'm on version 1.13.3. What version are you on?

Comment: @Adrian - yes, at the bottom. That was tested on 1.15.4. Just to verify - your page *definitely* filled the space previously occupied by the sidebar, right? I'll try removing the other code from Common.css and try again.

Comment: Yea it did fill the space previously occupied by the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks again Adrian. Update: when I included *only* the text above in Common.css the search bar and toolbox remained. So I think it is a skin issue. When I used this: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_hide_the_left_vertical_navigation_toolbar the whole sidebar vanished but did not reclaim the space. So I think it is a skin issue. I'll try other skins (we have a custom one).

Comment: Update: Adrian - it works with the Monobook skin - is that what you are using?

Comment: Yea I am using monobook. Good catch.

Comment: Thanks Adrian (and for your persistance here!). Any idea *why* monobook might behave differently to other skins?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer is a little late..

Entering following line to the MediaWiki:Common.css hides the navigation bar on all pages

```
#mw-panel .body { visibility: hidden; }
```

or

```
#mw-panel .body { opacity: 0; }
```

To hide the bar on a specific page add

```
.page-Pagename #mw-panel .body { visibility: hidden; }
```

"Pagename" is the name of the page (capitalized). Be really careful when editing the MediaWiki:Common.css page!